# Post to users facebook on achievement

Tags: facebook, social-media

If a user wants to do a quiz on my website and when he answers 3 questions correctly, he can post this to Facebook. If posted to Facebook by the user, then I need a call back to my website so I can reward the user.

Which steps does this process take? I think the following, can you confirm?

1. User enters my site
2. User answers questions
3. On the last page it says 'congrats, well done' And i allow the user to click a button that links somewhere. Where does it link to?
4. By clicking on the button a message gets posted 'Facebookname; Correctly answered 3 questions and is rewarded!
5. I receive a callback or if not possible i inmediately after the user presses button in step 3 reward the user.

Is this flow correct? Can more details (flow wise, technical, API references) be added?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that very easy by using Open Graph actions and objects. But the process is quite long to explain here. I suggest you read here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/